# Why is membase adress different each time kernel module is loaded?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I've been building a RTDM UART driver by using the Linux version as an example. The UART base address is supposed to be `0x80070000`, and when using the linux driver there is no problem as dmesg show:

```
80070000.serial: ttyAPP3 at MMIO 0x80070000 (irq = 234, base_baud = 1500000) is a 80070000.serial
mxs-auart 80070000.serial: Found APPUART 3.1.0
```

However, when I'm using the driver I'm builing I get a different adress each time I'm loading the module (such as `0xc8df6000`) and none of them are correct.

Here's the probe function I'm using:

```
static int rt_mxs_auart_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)

{
    const struct of_device_id *of_id =

            of_match_device(mxs_auart_dt_ids, &pdev->dev);

    int ret;
    struct resource *r;

    struct rtdm_device *dev;

    struct rt_mxs_auart_port *s;

    //allocate managed kernel memory

    s = devm_kzalloc(&pdev->dev, sizeof(*s), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (!s)
        return -ENOMEM;

    ret = rt_serial_mxs_probe_dt(s, pdev);

    if (ret < 0){
        return ret;
        }

    if (of_id) {

        pdev->id_entry = of_id->data;
        s->devtype = pdev->id_entry->driver_data;
    }

    r = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_MEM, 0);

    if (!r)
        return -ENXIO;

    //get irq line
    s->irq = platform_get_irq(pdev, 0);
    if (s->irq < 0)
        return -ENODEV;

    //base memory
    s->membase = ioremap(r->start, resource_size(r));

    if (IS_ERR(s->membase))
        return PTR_ERR(s->membase);


    /*define the rtdm_device*/
    dev = &s->rtdm_dev;
    dev->driver = &ida_driver;
    dev->label = "xeno_ida";
    dev->device_data = s;

    ret = mxs_get_clks(s, pdev); //activate clocks
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    s->uartclk = clk_get_rate(s->clk);
    s->fifosize = MXS_AUART_FIFO_SIZE;

    mxs_init_regs(s);

    ret = rtdm_dev_register(dev); //register driver in RTDM space

    if (ret)
        return ret;

    platform_set_drvdata(pdev, s); //add device-related data to device struct


    pr_info("Probe: Successful\n");
    pr_info("%s on IMX UART%d: membase=0x%p irq=%d uartclk=%d\n",
           dev->name, pdev->id, s->membase, s->irq, s->uartclk);

    return 0;
}
```

which is based on `mxs-auart.c` and `rt_imx_uart.c`.

For `membase` I'm using the same code as `mxs-auart.c` which is why I don't understand why I'm having this issue. My driver also freezes after some time when I try to `rmmod` it so I wonder if it is caused by this.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: `ioremap` doesn't guarantee any particular return value. Why do you think 0x80070000 is correct and 0xc8df6000 is not?

Comment: Because I'm working with AUART3 of my device and I know that its base memory is  0x80070000 according to the datasheet

Comment: 0x80070000 is a physical address, what you **pass** to `ioremap`. What `ioremap` **returns** is irrelevant. It could be anything.

Comment: oh I see! so does it mean that my `r` variable which is the return of `platform_get_resource` is 0x80070000 ?

Comment: Yes it should be.

Comment: Because you got an address from **virtual** memory address space.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. should probably post that as a - rather concise - answer.

Comment: `r->start` will hold the physical address.

Comment: it was indeed `r->start` that contained the physical adress, thank you Ian!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `ioremap` is a virtual address, not a physical one. It could be anywhere in the virtual address space.

The physical address is stored in `r->start` (the input of `ioremap`).